# When to close cursor in Android?

Tags: android, database-cursor

I have an app that uses a cursor to select data via `rawQuery` from an SQLite DB to populate a ListView in Android. Every time the user clicks on a listview item I create a new instance of Activity to re-populate listview.

Is it better to call `cursor.close()` and `db.close()` to avoid memory problems? I actually have `db.close()` in `OnDestroy()` of my activity.

Comment: maybe this could help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532427/how-do-i-close-the-cursor-and-database-safely

Answer (score 21):

You can close the `cursor` once you have retrieved the values for that particular object inside your method.

btw...You don't have to recreate a `listview` every time for a user click event. Just notify that there is some change in data of your adapter that has been set on the listview.

Something like

```
youradaptername.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should repopulate contents inside ur `listview` automatically.

Comment: where to add this line youradaptername.notifyDataSetChanged();? oncreate() or setitemclicklistener?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() needs to be called at a point wherein you know that data in your adapter has changed. This will force the listview to redraw its views which in turn helps you to see the new data in the list. Where you are going to invoke notifyDataSetChanged() depends on your need. Example refer to thispost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441298/android-call-notifydatasetchanged-from-asynctask

Answer (score 6):

Well if you are creating a new instance every time of the same Activity (though I am not sure its a good programming practice). You can close the cursor as soon as your have finished traversing / iterating through the source of the listview.

Example:

A sample implementation would be something like

```
//Pre cursor code
startManagingCursor(cursor);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        if (cursor.getString(0).equals(value)) {
            cursor.close();
            a = true;
            return a;
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

//Close cursor here, when its work is complete
cursor.close();

//Post cursor code ...
```

Comment: It's always good practice to wrap your cursor.close() in a finally clause. This way you make sure your cursor is closed, no matter if a RuntimeException is thrown during processing.