# Populating GridView from class extends BaseAdapter using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I want to show images on GridView layout using their URLs. first I created ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final String LOG_TAG = ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;

//  refers to image paths
    static ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return paths.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

//  create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
//          if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_item);
        try {
            String url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"+paths.get(position);
            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, url + "position=" + position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error:", e);
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

in method onPostExecute() which is implemented in FetchMovieTask class extends AsyncTask. I put data into ImageAdapter.paths and everything is fine.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
    if (results != null) {
        ImageAdapter.paths = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(results));
        for (int i = 0; i < ImageAdapter.paths.size(); i++)
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPostExecute: " + ImageAdapter.paths.get(i));
    }
}
```

in fragment class where I should populate gridView. ImageAdapter.path is still null

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_View);
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
    updateMovies();
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

public void updateMovies() {
    FetchMovieTask fetchMovieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
    fetchMovieTask.execute();
}
```

why ImageAdapter.paths is changed in FetchMovieTask class but not in ImageAdapter class?

Comment: *why ImageAdapter.paths is changed in FetchMovieTask class but not in ImageAdapter class?* huh? `ImageAdapter.paths` is a static field in `ImageAdapter` class so this question doesn't make sens **as it did change** ... the problem is does ImageAdapter instance was informed that underlaing data had changed(when the change appear)

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different Threads here. Your first Thread is working through the Code and also executes the getView before the Images are loaded. You need a Callback to deliver your results back to the UIThread:

Use an Interface for the Callback:

```
public interface UpdateMovieCallback {
    void processLoadImg(String[] results);
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements UpdateMovieCallback {

    public void updateMovies() {
        FetchMovieTask fetchMovieTask = new FetchMovieTask(this);
        fetchMovieTask.execute();
    }
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void processLoadImg(String[] results) {
        //Load Images to your Adapter here 
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The Use of a static method makes no sense here, you have to deal with your actual object:

```
public final class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    public FetchMovieTask(UpdateMovieCallback callback) {
        .
        .
        .
        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             // Executes first
        }

        .
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // Is called after doInBackground
            if (results != null) {
                callback.processLoadImg(results);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Another god advise for you is to learn something about Threads and Objects in Java. The Idea of a callback is that you can start Async Tasks or Threads and deliver callbacks/events back to your Main/UIThread.

[Threads Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))

Edit You could also implement it like this and skip the constructor:

```
public final class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[] results> {
        public FetchMovieTask() {}

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
             // Executes first
             return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
            // Is called after doInBackground
            if (results != null) {
                callback.processLoadImg(results);
            }
        }

}
```

Note: The third parameter of an async task is always the type of the result of the background computation. If it is a void, nothing is returned to onPostExecute, so your onPostExecute will never be called. Because onPostExecute() is called. If the third Parameter is an Array of Strings then onPostExecute(String[] results) is called.

[Asnyc Tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thankyou, but I have another problem. How you called onPostExecute inside FetchMovieTask 1-argument constructor? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sry I made a simple misstake, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is: you are setting the adapter before your FetchMovieTask complete the fetching your result.

So try changing your code as below:

First change the FetchMovieTask class as below.

```
 public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<param,progress,result>{

            private final OnFetchMovieCompletedListener listenerFetchMovieTask;

            public interface OnFetchMovieCompletedListener{
                void OnFetchMovieCompleted(ArrayList<String> paths );
            }

            public FetchMovieTask(OnFetchMovieCompletedListener listenerFetchMovieTask){
                this.listenerFetchMovieTask = listenerFetchMovieTask;
            }
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //your code goes here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
                if (results != null) {
                    if(listenerFetchMovieTask!=null){
                        listenerFetchMovieTask.OnFetchMovieCompleted(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(results)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Then change your fragment as below:

```
public class YourFragment  extends Fragment{

    private GridView gridView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_View);
        updateMovies();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void updateMovies() {
        FetchMovieTask fetchMovieTask = new FetchMovieTask(new OnFetchMovieCompletedListener(){

            @Override
            public void OnFetchMovieCompleted(ArrayList<String> paths) {
                ImageAdapter.paths = paths;
                ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
                gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        fetchMovieTask.execute();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by Editing the following:

1. moving FetchMovieTask to be inner class in ImageAdapter.
2. change paths to be non static field.
3. calling ImageAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); at the end of
   method onPostExecute()

More details: [Android call notifyDataSetChanged from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441298/android-call-notifydatasetchanged-from-asynctask)