# Attempt to invoke Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object refernce

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have tried adding the adapter in the onCreate() as well and it throws a null pointer exception with an error 'Attempt to invoke listVIew.setAdapter on a null object reference.

Here is the code where I use notifyDataSetChange() inside my Main Activity;

```
import static com.name.sample.Tab1.adapter;


public class Requests extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Cursor c =  myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM requests", null);

        int aIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int bIndex = c.getColumnIndex("nick");
        int cIndex = c.getColumnIndex("num");

        name.clear();
        nick.clear();
        number.clear();

        if (c.moveToFirst()){

            do {

                name.add(c.getString(aIndex));
                nick.add(c.getString(bIndex));
                number.add(c.getInt(cIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
```

Here is my Tab1 code
Here is the code for the Adapter

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

static ListView listNotifications;
final static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> nick = new ArrayList<>();

static ImageAdapter adapter;


public static class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public ImageAdapter (Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_with_icons, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_with_icons, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagePicture);

        textView.setText(values[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone


        return rowView;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1layout, container, false);

    String[] nameString = new String[name.size()];
    nameString = name.toArray(nameString);

    adapter = new ImageAdapter (getActivity(), nameString);



   listNotifications =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listNotifications);

listNotifications.setAdapter(adapter);




    return rootView;


}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `adapterClass.this.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExcecute()`

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    InvitedAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I used it as Tab1.InvitedAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); and it gives an error that it is not an enclosing class

Comment: you can use: `Tab1.InvitedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); cannot be referenced from a static context. Yes I changed the adapter to non-static as well.

Comment: the problem is your `adapter` is null in your `maiinActivity` you should initialize it or use the adapter class name ...to call `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: I tried removing the notifyDatasetChanged() completely and it works. Why is it happening?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help though. :)

Comment: here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441298/android-call-notifydatasetchanged-from-asynctask/16441389

Answer (score 1):

you have added a wrong adapter in the listview. it should be like this in onCreateView():

```
listNotifications.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Try this :)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but I actually changed the names to my variables to keep things simple but I missed one. This is not the solution. Thank you

Comment: I think your problem is with listview because it's not getting a proper adapter. @HamzaAmin