# SQLiteOpenHelper Failed to open database

Tags: android, sqlite

Using , I never had a problem until I got this error : `Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.project.projectapp.dev/databases/projectDB.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)`

I did not perform any changes on the database files, I wonder what could have gone wrong.

I tried changing database version, I tried emulator and real devices, nothing worked.

What could've potentially cause this error all of a sudden when I do not set Database file location anywhere in the code ?

EDIT :
I didn't want to go to that extend especially since the error does not point a relevant line but here we go :

```
package com.dash.dashapp.Utils;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dash.dashapp.Model.News;
import com.dash.dashapp.Model.Proposal;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sebas on 8/5/2017.
 */
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 20;
    public static final String TABLE_NEWS = "news";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_RSS_GUID = "rss_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_THUMBNAIL = "image";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date_pub";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String TABLE_PROPOSALS = "proposal";
    public static final String COLUMN_HASH = "hash"; //proposal hash [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name"; //proposal name [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_URL = "url"; //proposal URL set by the proposal owner during proposal submission [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_DW_URL = "dw_url"; //URL pointing to the DashCentral proposal page [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_DW_URL_COMMENTS = "dw_url_comments"; //URL pointing to the comment section on the DashCentral proposal page [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE_PROP = "title_prop"; //proposal title entered by the proposal owner on DashCentral [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_ADDED = "date_added"; //date, when the proposal was first seen on the network and has been added to the DashCentral database [datetime, UTC]
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_ADDED_HUMAN = "date_added_human"; //time since proposal has been added to the DashCentral database in words, eg. "6 days ago" [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_END = "date_end"; //date, when proposal payouts are expected to end [datetime, UTC]
    public static final String COLUMN_VOTING_DEADLINE_HUMAN = "voting_deadline_human"; //time until voting will be closed for this proposal, e.g "in 15 days" or "passed" [string]
    public static final String COLUMN_WILL_BE_FUNDED = "will_be_funded"; //is true when proposal has enough yes votes to become funded [boolean]
    public static final String COLUMN_REMAINING_YES_VOTES_UNTIL_FUNDING = "remaining_yes_votes_until_funding"; //amount of yes votes required for funding of this proposal [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_IN_NEXT_BUDGET = "in_next_budget"; //indicates, if proposal will be included within next budget and will be paid [boolean]
    public static final String COLUMN_MONTHLY_AMOUNT = "monthly_amount"; //amount of DASH that will be paid per month [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_TOTAL_PAYMENT_COUNT = "total_payment_amount"; //amount of payment cycles this proposal was intended to run [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_REMAINING_PAYMENT_COUNT = "remaining_payment_count"; //remaining payment cycles [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_YES = "yes"; //yes votes on this proposal [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_NO = "no"; //no votes on this proposal [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_ORDER = "order_display"; //the order value should be used to sort proposals in case the JSON order is not preserved correctly. The order is defined by a reddit like algo covering the time and the upvotes and downvotes on DashCentral [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT_AMOUNT = "comment_amount"; //amount of proposal comments posted on DashCentral [integer]
    public static final String COLUMN_OWNER_USERNAME = "owner_username"; //username of the proposal owner on DashCentral [string]
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dashDB.db";
    private static final String TAG = "MyDBHandler";


    public MyDBHandler(Context context, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NEWS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_NEWS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NEWS + "(" +
                        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        COLUMN_RSS_GUID + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_THUMBNAIL + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_DATE + " DATE," +
                        COLUMN_CONTENT + " TEXT" +
                        ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NEWS_TABLE);

        String CREATE_PROPOSAL_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROPOSALS + "(" +
                        COLUMN_HASH + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                        COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_URL + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_DW_URL + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_DW_URL_COMMENTS + " DATE," +
                        COLUMN_TITLE_PROP + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " DATE," +
                        COLUMN_DATE_ADDED_HUMAN + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_DATE_END + " DATE," +
                        COLUMN_VOTING_DEADLINE_HUMAN + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_WILL_BE_FUNDED + " BOOLEAN," +
                        COLUMN_REMAINING_YES_VOTES_UNTIL_FUNDING + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_IN_NEXT_BUDGET + " BOOLEAN," +
                        COLUMN_MONTHLY_AMOUNT + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_TOTAL_PAYMENT_COUNT + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_REMAINING_PAYMENT_COUNT + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_YES + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_NO + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_ORDER + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_COMMENT_AMOUNT + " INTEGER," +
                        COLUMN_OWNER_USERNAME + " TEXT" +
                        ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PROPOSAL_TABLE);

    }


    // NEWS
    public void addNews(News news) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_RSS_GUID, news.getGuid());
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, news.getTitle());
        values.put(COLUMN_THUMBNAIL, news.getThumbnail());

        SimpleDateFormat rssFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date dateRSS = new Date();
        try {
            dateRSS = rssFormat.parse(news.getPubDate());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sqlFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String dateSQL = sqlFormat.format(dateRSS);

        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, dateSQL);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTENT, news.getContent());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NEWS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public News findNews(String newsId) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NEWS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_RSS_GUID + "='" + newsId + "';";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        News news = new News();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            news.setGuid(cursor.getString(1));
            news.setTitle(cursor.getString(2));
            news.setThumbnail(cursor.getString(3));
            news.setPubDate(cursor.getString(4));
            news.setContent(cursor.getString(5));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            news = null;
        }
        db.close();
        return news;
    }

    public List<News> findAllNews(String filter) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Find list news");

        List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NEWS;
        if (filter != null) {
            query += " WHERE " + COLUMN_TITLE + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'";
        }
        query += " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE + " DESC;";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            News news = new News();
            news.setGuid(cursor.getString(1));
            news.setTitle(cursor.getString(2));
            news.setThumbnail(cursor.getString(3));
            news.setPubDate(cursor.getString(4));
            news.setContent(cursor.getString(5));
            newsList.add(news);
        }
        cursor.close();

        db.close();
        return newsList;
    }


    public boolean deleteNews(String newsId) {
        boolean result = false;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NEWS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_RSS_GUID + " =  '" + newsId + "';";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        News news = new News();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            news.setGuid(cursor.getString(1));
            db.delete(TABLE_NEWS, COLUMN_RSS_GUID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(news.getGuid())});
            cursor.close();
            result = true;
        }
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    public void deleteAllNews() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NEWS);
        db.close();
    }


    // PROPOSALS
    public void addProposal(Proposal proposal) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_HASH, proposal.getHash());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, proposal.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_URL, proposal.getUrl());
        values.put(COLUMN_DW_URL, proposal.getDw_url());
        values.put(COLUMN_DW_URL_COMMENTS, proposal.getDw_url_comments());
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE_PROP, proposal.getTitle());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE_ADDED, proposal.getDate_added());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE_ADDED_HUMAN, proposal.getDate_added_human());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE_END, proposal.getDate_end());
        values.put(COLUMN_VOTING_DEADLINE_HUMAN, proposal.getVoting_deadline_human());
        values.put(COLUMN_WILL_BE_FUNDED, proposal.isWill_be_funded());
        values.put(COLUMN_REMAINING_YES_VOTES_UNTIL_FUNDING, proposal.getRemaining_yes_votes_until_funding());
        values.put(COLUMN_IN_NEXT_BUDGET, proposal.isIn_next_budget());
        values.put(COLUMN_MONTHLY_AMOUNT, proposal.getMonthly_amount());
        values.put(COLUMN_TOTAL_PAYMENT_COUNT, proposal.getTotal_payment_count());
        values.put(COLUMN_REMAINING_PAYMENT_COUNT, proposal.getRemaining_payment_count());
        values.put(COLUMN_YES, proposal.getYes());
        values.put(COLUMN_NO, proposal.getNo());
        values.put(COLUMN_ORDER, proposal.getOrder());
        values.put(COLUMN_COMMENT_AMOUNT, proposal.getComment_amount());
        values.put(COLUMN_OWNER_USERNAME, proposal.getOwner_username());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PROPOSALS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Proposal findProposal(String proposalHash) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROPOSALS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_HASH + "='" + proposalHash + "';";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Proposal proposal = new Proposal();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            proposal.setHash(cursor.getString(0));
            proposal.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            proposal.setUrl(cursor.getString(2));
            proposal.setDw_url(cursor.getString(3));
            proposal.setDw_url_comments(cursor.getString(4));
            proposal.setTitle(cursor.getString(5));
            proposal.setDate_added(cursor.getString(6));
            proposal.setDate_added_human(cursor.getString(7));
            proposal.setDate_end(cursor.getString(8));
            proposal.setVoting_deadline_human(cursor.getString(9));
            proposal.setWill_be_funded(cursor.getInt(10) != 0);
            proposal.setRemaining_yes_votes_until_funding(cursor.getInt(11));
            proposal.setIn_next_budget(cursor.getInt(12) != 0);
            proposal.setMonthly_amount(cursor.getInt(13));
            proposal.setTotal_payment_count(cursor.getInt(14));
            proposal.setRemaining_payment_count(cursor.getInt(15));
            proposal.setYes(cursor.getInt(16));
            proposal.setNo(cursor.getInt(17));
            proposal.setOrder(cursor.getInt(18));
            proposal.setComment_amount(cursor.getInt(19));
            proposal.setOwner_username(cursor.getString(20));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            proposal = null;
        }
        db.close();
        return proposal;
    }

    public List<Proposal> findAllProposals(String filter) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Find list proposals");

        List<Proposal> proposalsList = new ArrayList<>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROPOSALS;
        if (filter != null) {
            query += " WHERE " + COLUMN_TITLE_PROP + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'";
        }
        query += " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE_END + " ASC;";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Proposal proposal = new Proposal();
            proposal.setHash(cursor.getString(0));
            proposal.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            proposal.setUrl(cursor.getString(2));
            proposal.setDw_url(cursor.getString(3));
            proposal.setDw_url_comments(cursor.getString(4));
            proposal.setTitle(cursor.getString(5));
            proposal.setDate_added(cursor.getString(6));
            proposal.setDate_added_human(cursor.getString(7));
            proposal.setDate_end(cursor.getString(8));
            proposal.setVoting_deadline_human(cursor.getString(9));
            proposal.setWill_be_funded(cursor.getInt(10) != 0);
            proposal.setRemaining_yes_votes_until_funding(cursor.getInt(11));
            proposal.setIn_next_budget(cursor.getInt(12) != 0);
            proposal.setMonthly_amount(cursor.getInt(13));
            proposal.setTotal_payment_count(cursor.getInt(14));
            proposal.setRemaining_payment_count(cursor.getInt(15));
            proposal.setYes(cursor.getInt(16));
            proposal.setNo(cursor.getInt(17));
            proposal.setOrder(cursor.getInt(18));
            proposal.setComment_amount(cursor.getInt(19));
            proposal.setOwner_username(cursor.getString(20));
            proposalsList.add(proposal);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return proposalsList;
    }


    public boolean deleteProposal(String proposalHash) {
        boolean result = false;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROPOSALS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_HASH + " =  '" + proposalHash + "';";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Proposal proposal = new Proposal();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            proposal.setHash(cursor.getString(0));
            db.delete(TABLE_PROPOSALS, COLUMN_HASH + " = ?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(proposal.getHash())});
            cursor.close();
            result = true;
        }
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    public void deleteAllProposals() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_PROPOSALS);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: One reason for such a non-error is when you try to execute an empty SQL statement. Please post your code.

Comment: Code added after edit

Comment: Quickly scanning the code: nothing terribly wrong but you're leaking cursors (and therefore database refcounts don't go to zero) by not closing the cursor if `moveToFirst()` returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me time ago, I was not closing the database after each use and I supposed it got corrupted at some point.

What I did was check all the database connections and add all the necessary code to close it after each use. Then, I reinstalled the app to create the database again.

Lucky or not, I didn't have the same problem again.

Also, now that I see your code, you should always close your cursors and not only when cursor.moveToFirst() returns true.

Comment: I seem to be opening and closing connections in every query unfortunately, but thanks for the help !

Comment: I see, every time getWritableDatabase() is called the database is closed before returning the data, that looks good. However, I would close the cursors always and not only when cursor.moveToFirst() returns true. Some people also considers a good practice to wrap your cursor.close() in a finally clause. To make sure your cursor is closed, no matter if an exception is thrown during processing. That might be the cause your database got corrupt, in my opinion.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123317/when-to-close-cursor-in-android

Comment: Well I don't get the whole story but I did what you said, changed database number, performed full uninstall an re-install and it seems to be working. Sadly it is not too clear what was happening but regardless, thanks.